# sprite kit physicsBody around circles

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, sprite, skphysicsbody

So guy and girls 
I got this sprite and i was wounding how do i create a circle physics body around it. Maybe using something with alpha.

What I currently have **ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:ball.size];**

[image]

**bodyWithRectangleOfSize** just puts a square over the sprite right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a circular physics body you can either use:

```
myNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:10.0];
```

or

```
myNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:10 center:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
```

You would specify a center only if you are looking for your physics body to have an offset from your node's center.